# Consul members fail

Tags: agent, consul

I am trying to do this tutorial--> [tutorialConsul](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-consul-in-a-production-environment-on-ubuntu-14-04)

When I run:

```
   ikerlan@ikerlan-docker:~$ consul members

 Node            Address           Status  Type    Build  Protocol
  ikerlan-docker  172.16.8.37:8301  alive   client  0.3.0  2
  172.16.8.191    10.0.2.15:8301    alive   server  0.3.0  2
  172.16.8.192    10.0.2.15:8301    alive   server  0.3.0  2
  172.16.8.193    10.0.2.15:8301    alive   server  0.3.0  2

ikerlan@ikerlan-docker:~$ consul members

 Node            Address           Status  Type    Build  Protocol
    ikerlan-docker  172.16.8.37:8301  alive   client  0.3.0  2
    172.16.8.191    10.0.2.15:8301    failed  server  0.3.0  2
    172.16.8.192    10.0.2.15:8301    alive   server  0.3.0  2
    172.16.8.193    10.0.2.15:8301    failed  server  0.3.0  2

ikerlan@ikerlan-docker:~$ consul members

    Node            Address           Status  Type    Build  Protocol
    ikerlan-docker  172.16.8.37:8301  alive   client  0.3.0  2
    172.16.8.191    10.0.2.15:8301    failed  server  0.3.0  2
    172.16.8.192    10.0.2.15:8301    alive   server  0.3.0  2
    172.16.8.193    10.0.2.15:8301    alive   server  0.3.0  2
```

I can see the members alive, but if I run again some of that members failed, and then other ones alive and failed..

I think the leader, remove the members so they failed, and they try to connect but then they are removed.

I am working with virtualbox machines, and I see that consul takes all the machines with the same address, but I have configure consul to use eth1 interface that is the IP there appear in Node(name)

What could it be?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please post your consul configuration as part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different nodes must not have the same address. This will confuse Consul, as Consul will use this address to connect to the nodes.

Use the `bind_addr` configuration option to ensure that consul uses the right interface and IP address on each machine consul doesn't pick the right address automatically. [By default Consul picks the "first" private address it finds](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_bind) and this might not work in your setup.

The version you're running seems to be quite old (0.3.0). The current version is 0.6.0.

Comment: Thanks very much @ahus1 it works perfectly, I have version 0.3.0 because I have some problem with the 0.6.0, but I think the problem would be this, so I'll try with the current version 0.6.0.